# C Output: Adding a custom filename to a user input directory

Tags: c, file-io

What I want to do is take in two arguments, a filename and an output directory as such:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    readfile(argv[1]);

    //manipulates the file

    writefile(argv[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm very new to C so I ultimately would like for the output file to be named `output` and if it is run again `output2`, and so on.

How would I take `argv[2]`, which is just a directory, and have it turn into `output1`, `output2`, etc?

Would I take the `argv[2]` and copy it to another string and add my file names to the end of that and pass that into `fopen`? Or is there a more elegant method?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use file pointers and `fprintf(pFile,data,filename)`

pFile is your FILE*
data is what you want to write to file
Filename is "output.txt"